# Blender connected proportional edit in UV/Image editor not working

Tags: transforms, vertices

I'm trying to proportionally edit some vertices using the connected mode in the UV/Image editor. According to [the Blender manual on proportional editting](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/proportional_edit.html), I should be able to edit vertices that are both close (in spatial coordinates) while simultaneously ignoring those that are far away topographically.

This is not what happens though. It seems as though it edits the vertices with normal proportional edit, ignoring the fact that some of the vertices are far away topographically.

Here's a picture
[image: Not working]

Is this the expected behavior for this tool or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: Are those 2 disconnected meshes ? It isn't seen there, but the meshes have to be not connected by any vertex.

Comment: They are connected yes. But according to the manual `This means that you can proportionally edit the vertices in a finger of a hand without affecting the other fingers. While the other vertices are physically close (in 3D space), they are far away following the topological edge connections of the mesh.` this leads me to think they can still be connected

Comment: They can be connected; however for absolute moving lock of any geometry it should be unconnected. Try working with simple proportional edit and change influence radius; you should see the difference between the modes.

Comment: @MrZak Changing the radius doesn't give me the transform I want unfortunately because I still want the large radius, just not affect the vertices on the other side of the gap. Maybe they're just too close topographically as well because I compared using both simple proportional and connected proportional and they affect the vertices that are farther away just the same amount. So I don't really know what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately proportional editing in the UV editor works differently to the 3Dview. In the 3Dview connected proportional editing will only move vertices that are directly attached to the selected vertices that you are moving. In the UV editor all points that are indirectly connected are influenced by proportional editing.

A possible solution is to select only the vertices you want to move (in the 3Dview), the unselected vertices will not be visible in the UV editor and will not be moved when you move the nearby points. Note that this can tear apart neighbouring faces at the edge of the selection.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing to get the result I wanted even if it was a bit more of a pain. Thanks for answering the question too.

Answer (score 1):

you can try temporarily pinning some vertices in the UV map with  <kbd>Shift-P</kbd>

Comment: I was looking for something like this! Thanks